# Como enlazo Bitbucket a mi repositorio en xampp

Tags: git, xampp, bitbucket

tengo mi proyecto de PHP en un servidor propio en Xampp (c:xampp/htdocs/proyecto) Lo que quiero es usar GIT para el trabajo en el equipo. Instalé bitbucket server para esto, puedo crear repositorios en este pero no se como puedo hacer para que trabaje directamente con mi repo en xampp, que al hacer push este se actualicé en el proyecto que despliego a través del servidor de xampp. Ayuda Por favor.

Comment: creo que tu pregunta es como subir un repositorio en GitServer privado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con bitbucket puedes usar herramientas como SourceTree que administran tus archivos, brances, etc. 
 -> https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Si al no recuerdo, lo primero es crear un repositorio en bitbucket, luego de esto, copiar tu repositorio usando Sourcetree a la direccion de Xampp (htdocs).
Luego de esto, puedes meterle lo que quieras dentro, y hacer commit + push para subir tus cambios. Quienes copien tu repositorio y tengan acceso podrán hacer cambios en el.

Use este metodo durante los estudios, espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, voy a investigar como se usa sourcetree. Saludos.

Comment: No es complicado, solo administra los push, pull, commit de los archivos, muestra los cambios, quien los hizo, o que ramas se trabajan. (asi puedes vigilar a tus compañeros ademas). Si termina siendo esta tu respuesta no olvides marcarla.

Comment: si obvio, si me funciona me habrás ayudado mucho, ya que se usar git a nivel usuario junto con github a modo personal, pero gestionar un equipo en un servidor privado, no tengo mucha idea de como se hace.

Comment: Ayúdanos a responder preguntas realizadas en base a [ask], para mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, saludos.